# Representations and conformal weights for a Kac Moody algebra

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9210122) they state the folowing: (for $\hat {\mathfrak g}$ a Kac Moody algebra $\mathfrak g\oplus c\mathbb C$)

[image]

I remember seeing this stated somewhere else before, but I cannot for the life of me find a text where they prove it (any of the two parts of the statement). So I would like to know where I can find a proof or at least an idea for one.

Comment: Which statement? The fact that level k highest-weight representations are labelled like that? Have you looked in Chapter 12 of Kac's _Infinite-dimensional Lie algebras_?

Comment: @Joppy Both statements: that, and the expression for the conformal weight.
I skimmed most chapters of that book, but didn't find anything. If you say the answer is in there then I will look at that chapter again closely.

Comment: Equation 12.8.11 has that exact formula. Kac calls it a "vacuum anomaly".

Comment: @Joppy I now see that I have been using the 1st edition of the book, which is missing that part (section 12.8 is an exercise section). But in the 3rd edition the formula is there, as you say.